WSL Ubuntu 20.04.06 installed in new location, leaving Ubuntu 20.04.3 in place
WSL Ubuntu 20.04.06 installed in new location, leaving Ubuntu 20.04.3 in place, but when I one a new Ubuntu window I get the new version and I had to re/create a new user.
As far as I can tell, only the Windows file system can see both of these distributions.
I.e., I can't use bash commands to copy or link the old file to the new system.
Also, the apps I've installed are not available, e.g. gcc.
I think I have to assume that the underlying libraries have changed. Is this true?
I believe I can use the explorer to copy my home directory. I assume any compiled executables should be rebuilt. Maybe not if I'm using dynamically loaded libraries.
Do I need to reinstall all the applications I'm using gcc, Python, etc?
Is there a way to point to the old version of Ubuntu? It seems that the WSL command does not recognize the subversion.
